# Combining a query displays incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Apologies for the big snippets of code but I need to display them to show the relevant investigation I have compiled.

Below I have two separate queries, one checking for crew members in a particular flight from the **staging** schema (`Staging.SabreAssignedCrew`) table and the other is a comparison on the **data** schema tables where after connecting all the relevant tables together, I get the crew information per flight:

---

`Staging.SabreAssignedCrew` table

```
SELECT 
*
, Airline + CAST(FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + Suffix AS StagingFlight 
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Airline + CAST(FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + Suffix  ORDER BY UpdateId DESC) AS StageRowNumber
FROM Staging.SabreAssignedCrew
WHERE Airline + CAST(FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + Suffix = 'LS627' AND DepartureDate = '2016-09-04'
```

---

`Data` schema tables

```
SELECT 
cd.CrewUpdateID
, cd.IsPassive
, cd.CrewBase
, cd.CrewCategory
, cd.CrewType
, cd.EmployeeNumber
, cd.FirstName
, cd.LastName
, c.UpdateID
, c.LegKey
, c.UpdateReceived
, DataFlight
, l.ScheduledDepartureDate
, l.ScheduledDepartureAirport
FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LegKey ORDER BY UpdateID DESC) AS RowNumber FROM Data.Crew) c
INNER JOIN 
Data.CrewDetail cd
ON c.UpdateID = cd.CrewUpdateID
AND cd.IsPassive = 0
AND RowNumber = 1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT *, Carrier + CAST(FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + Suffix AS DataFlight FROM Data.Leg) l
ON c.LegKey = l.LegKey
WHERE DataFlight = 'LS627' AND ScheduledDepartureDate = '2016-09-04'
```

The results of both queries show that there are 6 crew members (6 rows) in the flight:

[image]

Now what I am trying to do is combine the queries into one using and perform a SUM to ensure the correct crew members are on board the flight. However, the results are incorrect as it outputd below:

[image]

We know there are 6 crew members in the flight, so it should display for the **staging** schema 2 `StagingCabinCrew`and 4 `StagingCockpitCrew`and exactly the same values for the **data** schema. This is all determined by the `CrewType` field from both **staging** and **data** schema tables.

I am assuming I am doing something wrong in my combined query but I am not sure what it is as running the two queries mentioned above separately in the combined query displays the correct results, but executing the whole combined query displays the wrong value. What needs to be fixed?

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
cd.CrewUpdateID
, cd.IsPassive
, cd.CrewBase
, cd.CrewCategory
, cd.CrewType
, cd.EmployeeNumber
, cd.FirstName
, cd.LastName
, c.UpdateID
, c.LegKey
, c.UpdateReceived
, DataFlight
, l.ScheduledDepartureDate
, l.ScheduledDepartureAirport
FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LegKey ORDER BY UpdateID DESC) AS RowNumber FROM Data.Crew) c
INNER JOIN 
Data.CrewDetail cd
ON c.UpdateID = cd.CrewUpdateID
AND cd.IsPassive = 0
AND RowNumber = 1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT *, Carrier + CAST(FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + Suffix AS DataFlight FROM Data.Leg) l
ON c.LegKey = l.LegKey
WHERE DataFlight = 'LS627' AND ScheduledDepartureDate = '2016-09-04'
)
SELECT
StagingFlight
, sac.DepartureDate
, sac.DepartureAirport
, cte.DataFlight
, cte.ScheduledDepartureDate
, cte.ScheduledDepartureAirport
, SUM(CASE WHEN sac.CREWTYPE = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StagingCabinCrew
, SUM(CASE WHEN sac.CREWTYPE = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StagingCockpitCrew
, SUM(CASE WHEN cte.CrewType = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DataCabinCrew
, SUM(CASE WHEN cte.CrewType = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DataCockpitCrew
FROM 
(
SELECT 
*
, Airline + CAST(FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + Suffix AS StagingFlight 
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Airline + CAST(FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + Suffix  ORDER BY UpdateId DESC) AS StageRowNumber
FROM Staging.SabreAssignedCrew--
WHERE Airline + CAST(FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + Suffix = 'LS627' AND DepartureDate = '2016-09-04') 
sac

LEFT JOIN CTE cte
ON StagingFlight = DataFlight
AND sac.DepartureDate = cte.ScheduledDepartureDate
AND sac.DepartureAirport = cte.ScheduledDepartureAirport
AND sac.CREWTYPE = cte.CrewType
WHERE StagingFlight = 'LS627' AND DepartureDate = '2016-09-04' AND StageRowNumber = 1

GROUP BY 
StagingFlight
, sac.DepartureDate
, sac.DepartureAirport
, cte.DataFlight
, cte.ScheduledDepartureDate
, cte.ScheduledDepartureAirport
```

Comment: At begining try to make your qry much more easier
- "Airline + CAST(FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + Suffix" could be computed persisted column - will be more readable
- create agregation for crew (group by StagingFlight, sac.DepartureDate, sac.DepartureAirport) into temporary table or view
- you don't need row_number in your qry (group by will be enough)

Comment: @deadsheep39 Do you want to stick your comment as an answer so if it works I can mark it? I know how to do views or temp table but may as well include an example for others to see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create column for stagingflight (you will probably use apropriete index). Please set always the size of varchar (for example varchar --> varchar(30)).

   ```
   alter table staging.sabreassignedcrew 
   add stagingflight as cast(airline + cast(flightnumber as varchar(5)) + suffix as varchar(25)) persisted
   ```
2. create views.

   ```
   CREATE VIEW Staging.vw_SabreAssignedCrewCount
   AS
   SELECT 
       StagingFlight, 
       DepartureDate, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sac.CREWTYPE = 'F' THEN EmployeeNumber END) AS StagingCabinCrewCnt,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sac.CREWTYPE = 'C' THEN EmployeeNumber END) AS StagingCockpitCrewCnt
   FROM Staging.SabreAssignedCrew
   GROUP BY StagingFlight, DepartureDate
   ```

The second view for the second table.

3. You don't need rownumbers, CTE. Only easy join on 2 grouped selections.

Comment: Thanks Deadsheep39 for your answer, sadly I have found out I have permissions restricted in creating views or altering tables, so I will have to use CTEs for now. I have been trying to fgigure it out in last two hours but still no luck. Have you got an idea on where the problem is and be able to provide a code snippet of a possible fix please?

Comment: If you haven't permission to create view, try if you can create temp table (#). Insert first selection from group by into temp table and overview if there are your expected results - if it's ok, get the second selection and try overview your temporary results per partes.